# Unable to save Assets entries in Grid

Tags: assets, grid, publisher

I'm using Assets 2.6 on EE 2.10.2 running with Publisher 1.6.8

I'm able to define Assets fields within Grid fields.

The resulting Asset Fields work insofar as they open Assets and allow the selection of items. However upon saving the selected items are not stored in the Grid field.

Other fields within the Grid work fine, and there are no apparent problems with the rest of the site.  Assets entries stored in Matrix fields are fully accessible / work OK: but need to move to Grid as Matrix not being updated to EE3... :(

Editing a Grid with Assets entries previously saved within (created by external importer) results in the entry being deleted (or not saved).

Is this something that has happened elsewhere?  Any ideas what I can do about it?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I don't offer support through Stack Exchange. But you should try upgrading to the latest version first. Always upgrade before submitting a bug report... the bug may already be fixed.

Comment: Hi Brian.  Thanks for the comment - but what are you suggesting I upgrade?  Assets and Publisher are (AFAIK) both latest versions, and EE 2.10.3 is only a minor upgrade with nothing mentioned that has anything to do with this (https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/about/changelog.html#version-2-10-3) - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a bug in Publisher: seems to be referred obscurely as a "[Grid persistence error](https://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher/change-log)" in changelog that was fixed in 1.6.10.

Would have got there sooner if Brian Litzinger had actually said as much in his posting above rather than just hinting at...